# Como filtrar um array de objetos utilizando outros array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou tentando criar um filtro de produtos recentes que são buscados (ao começar a digitar, ele já aparece os produtos encontrados, como se fosse um "like"), tenho uma variável global que é um array, e a partir dela eu salvo em outro array os dados do *return item*, como pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo:

```
produtosFiltrados: function() {

let articles_array = this.produtos;
let searchString = this.$myGlobalStuff.searchArray; //Global

searchString.map(searchString => searchString.trim().toLowerCase());

  articles_array2 = articles_array.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
      return item;
    }
  });

  return articles_array2;
}
```

Porém quando a minha variável *this.$myGlobalStuff.searchArray* possui mais de um item o meu *articles_array2* sempre fica vazio quando é chamada a função.

Para entender melhor o problema, simulei o problema no link abaixo:

https://codepen.io/haykou/pen/gdZQJZ

Como pode ser visto se for adicionado um item na variavel

```
searchArray: ['dermodex']
```

O filtro não funciona mais.

Comment: Cria um snippet com um código funcional pra facilitar. Esse código que tu postou é um computedProperty? Um *method*?

Comment: vou tentar melhorar, é um computed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tentei reproduzir teu código no snippet abaixo. Pelo que pude perceber tem dois erros mais graves que impedem o funcionamento.

1. Na linha:

   ```
   searchString.map(searchString => searchString.trim().toLowerCase());
   ```

   O método [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) retorna um novo array com o resultado do callback aplicado a todos os elementos do array. No seu caso, você está fazendo o cálculo e não está guardando o resultado em uma variável.
2. Na linha:

   ```
   item.nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString)
   ```

   O método [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) procura uma ocorrência de uma substring em outra string, mas pela lógica do seu código me parece que você quer usar o [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) que tem função semelhante, porém procura pela ocorrência dentro de um array. Então acredito que o que você quer usar nessa linha seja:

   ```
   searchString.indexOf(item.nome.toLowerCase())
   ```

---

#### EDIT

Modifiquei o código para se comportar como um `LIKE` e como um `OR`. A função ficou assim:

```
function produtosFiltrados() {
    let sanitize = str => str.trim().toLowerCase();
    let strings = this.myGlobalStuff.searchArray.map(sanitize);

    return this.produtos.filter(function(item) {
        let nome = sanitize(item.nome);
        return strings.some(str => ~nome.indexOf(str));
    });
}
```

Explicação do código:

```
let sanitize = str => str.trim().toLowerCase();
```

Apenas salva a função que sanitiza as string, pois ela é usada mais de uma vez no código. Esta função poderia estar em outro lugar, fora da `computedProperty` (talvez até devesse).

---

```
let strings = this.myGlobalStuff.searchArray.map(sanitize);
```

Sanitiza todos os termos de pesquisa antes de usá-los.

---

```
return this.produtos.filter(function(item) {
    let nome = sanitize(item.nome);
    return strings.some(str => ~nome.indexOf(str));
});
```

É aqui onde tudo acontece:

- `this.produtos.filter(...)` vai retornar um array apenas com os elementos cuja função retorne um valor [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (que, quando convertido para *boolean* é verdadeiro). Ex.:

  ```
  // Filtra apenas os números ímpares
  [0, 1, 2, 3].filter(x => x % 2)  // [1, 3]
  ```
- `strings.some(...)`, o método [`Array.some(function)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) aplica a `function` nos elementos do `Array` e retorna `true` se qualquer um dos retornos da função seja [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Ou seja, funciona como um `OR` (e o [`Array.every(function)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) funciona como um `AND`, apenas para curiosidade). Ex.:

  ```
  // Testa se tem algum número ímpar no array
  [0, 1, 2, 3].some(x => x % 2)  // true
  [0, 2, 4, 6].some(x => x % 2)  // false
  ```
- `~nome.indexOf(str)`, o método [`String.indexOf(substring)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) retorna a posição da substring dentro da string ou -1 caso a substring não exista dentro da string. Dito isso, para sabermos se a substring foi encontrada basta testarmos se `x.indexOf(y) !== -1`, porém, como curiosidade, se você converter -1 para uma representação binária você vai perceber que é um binário exatamente oposto do 0 (Ver sobre [complemento de 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers)).

  ```
  (-1 >>> 0).toString(2) // "11111111111111111111111111111111"
  (0).toString(2)        // "00000000000000000000000000000000"
  ```

  <sup>Para entender o `>>> 0` veja [esta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16155417/1284458)</sup>

  Então se você aplicar um `NOT` binário (com o operador `~`), qualquer número diferente de -1 será `!== 0` que é um valor [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) e o -1 será falso. Então, na conversão para `boolean`:

  ```
  x.indexOf(y) !== -1
  ```

  É equivalente a:

  ```
  ~x.indexOf(y)
  ```

---

Então a função:

```
return this.produtos.filter(function(item) {
    let nome = sanitize(item.nome);
    return strings.some(str => ~nome.indexOf(str));
});
```

Significa:

> Filtre todos os produtos cujo nome contenha qualquer um dos termos de pesquisa.

---

Código funcionando:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        myGlobalStuff: {  // fake da Global
            searchArray: ["1", "5"]
        },
        produtos: [
            {id: 1, nome: "Produto 1"},
            {id: 2, nome: "Produto 2"},
            {id: 3, nome: "Produto 3"},
            {id: 4, nome: "Produto 4"},
            {id: 5, nome: "Produto 5"},
            {id: 6, nome: "Produto 6"},
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        produtosFiltrados: function() {
            // Salva a função apenas por praticidade
            let sanitize = str => str.trim().toLowerCase();
            let strings = this.myGlobalStuff.searchArray.map(sanitize);
            
            return this.produtos.filter(function(item) {
                let nome = sanitize(item.nome);
                return strings.some(str => ~nome.indexOf(str));
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <strong>Produtos</strong>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="p in produtos" :key="p.id">
      [{{ p.id }}] {{ p.nome }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <strong>Produtos Filtrados</strong>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="p in produtosFiltrados" :key="p.id">
      [{{ p.id }}] {{ p.nome }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: só uma duvida, no codepen que eu fiz, a função estava funcionando como um "like", inserindo apenas alguns caracteres no searchArray, ele já me retornava o resultado. Consigo fazer o mesmo com os ajustes que você fez?

Comment: Ah tá.. eu preciso modificar o código então. Não vou poder fazer isso agora, mas assim que eu fizer eu aviso aqui

Comment: tranquilo, estou tentando acertar aqui

Comment: Modifiquei o código para funcionar como um `LIKE` e um `OR`. A sessão **EDIT** contém toda a explicação das modificações